# Observable.timer is not triggered in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

i m trying to send requests every 5 seconds to server but somehow the timer is not triggered. I dont get any error in the console. Any idea why its not working ?

Thanks in advance !

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AzureService from "../_services/AzureService";
import  "../_css/TFSBuilds";
import {FormikBag as props} from "formik";
import {timer} from "rxjs";
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';



class Build extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            builds: []
        };
    }
     componentDidMount() {
             timer(0,5000).pipe(switchMap(()=> {

                  AzureService.send("ObCloud").then((data)=>{
                      let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
                      this.createChartObjects(groupedData)
                  });
                  AzureService.send("Kenevo%20Adjustment").then((data)=>{
                      let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
                      this.createChartObjects(groupedData)
                  });
                  AzureService.send("cockpit").then((data)=>{
                      let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
                      this.createChartObjects(groupedData)

                  });


              }));

        }
```

Comment: My guess is, `this` binding. You can add inside one of the `then(...)` a `console.log(this)` to check whether `this` points at the instance of `Build` - my guess is, it doesn't.

Comment: could you give an example about what you mean ?

Comment: the methods are not trigerred even once.. So writing console.log olse would bring anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not subscribing to send it in flight:

Try:

```
timer(0,5000).subscribe(() => {
  AzureService.send("ObCloud").then((data)=>{
                      let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
                      this.createChartObjects(groupedData)
                  });
                  AzureService.send("Kenevo%20Adjustment").then((data)=>{
                      let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
                      this.createChartObjects(groupedData)
                  });
                  AzureService.send("cockpit").then((data)=>{
                      let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
                      this.createChartObjects(groupedData)

                  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I get it now. There's no subscription to get the business going.

```
             timer(0,5000).pipe(switchMap(()=> {
```

You can, for example, add `.subscribe()` at the end, or even convert replace your `.pipe(switchMap(() => /* code here */)` with `.subscribe(/* the same code */)`.